# Restrict inserting data in master table if child table has one record for the sysdate in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a `stored-procedure` which inserts the records in Master table as well as child table. The logic is the child table can have multiple entries currently. But due to multiple entries sometimes if we try to insert the same records with two different browsers duplicacy is happening in child table.

Even we want the multiple entries for that record but not the duplicate ones.

Below is my table information .

`TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS`   **Master table**
`TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS` **Child table**

Also below is the SP and is table description.

```
PROCEDURE INS_WORKFLOW
(
  PSPAN_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.SPAN_ID%TYPE,
    PLINK_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.LINK_ID%TYPE,
    PCREATED_BY IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.CREATED_BY%TYPE,
    PMAINTENANCEZONECODE IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.MAINTENANCEZONECODE%TYPE,
    PMAINTENANCEZONENAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.MAINTENANCEZONENAME%TYPE,
    PMAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH%TYPE,
    PSTATUS_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.STATUS_ID%TYPE,
    PHOTO_OFFERED_DATE IN NVARCHAR2,
    PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.APPROV_REJECT_REMARK%TYPE,
    PISABDMISSING IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.ISABDMISSING%TYPE,
    PHOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.HOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH%TYPE,
    PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID%TYPE,
    PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME%TYPE,
    PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID%TYPE,
    PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME%TYPE,
    PSPAN_TYPE IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.SPAN_TYPE%TYPE,
    POUTMSG OUT NVARCHAR2
) 
AS
PJOB_PROGRESS_ID NUMBER:=0;
PJOB_ID NUMBER :=0;
PCNT_JOBID NUMBER :=-1;
PNELENGTH NUMBER:=0;
PUGLENGTH NUMBER:=0;
PARLENGTH NUMBER:=0;

BEGIN
    --execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format = ''DD/MM/YYYY''';
    IF PSPAN_TYPE = 'INTRACITY' OR PSPAN_TYPE = 'ENTERPRISE' THEN
    BEGIN
         SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) INTO PCNT_JOBID 
            FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
            WHERE LINK_ID = PLINK_ID
            AND MAINTENANCEZONECODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE;
            
            SELECT  ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS UG_LEN
       ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%CLAMP%'  THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS AR_LEN

               INTO PNELENGTH,PUGLENGTH,PARLENGTH
          FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER 
    --FROM APP_FTTX.span@sat
              WHERE RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID = PLINK_ID
              AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
              AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE
              GROUP BY RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE;
    END;
    ELSIF PSPAN_TYPE = 'INTERCITY' THEN
    BEGIN
          SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) INTO PCNT_JOBID 
              FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
              WHERE SPAN_ID = PSPAN_ID
              AND MAINTENANCEZONECODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE;
        ---CR981 implemenation
         IF LENGTH(PSPAN_ID) = 9  THEN
         BEGIN              
           SELECT  ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS UG_LEN
       ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%CLAMP%'  THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS AR_LEN

               INTO PNELENGTH,PUGLENGTH,PARLENGTH
         FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER 
    --FROM APP_FTTX.span@sat
              WHERE RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID = PSPAN_ID
              AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
              AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE
              GROUP BY RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE;
         END;
         ELSE
         BEGIN
          SELECT  ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH,
        ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS UG_LEN
   ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%CLAMP%'  THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS AR_LEN
              
               INTO PNELENGTH,PUGLENGTH,PARLENGTH
          FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER 
    --FROM APP_FTTX.span@sat
              WHERE RJ_SPAN_ID = PSPAN_ID
              AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
              AND (NOT REGEXP_LIKE (RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,'_(9)','i') OR RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL)
              AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE
              GROUP BY RJ_SPAN_ID,RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE;
         END;
         END IF;
        
    END;
    END IF;
    IF PCNT_JOBID = 0 THEN
    BEGIN        
        INSERT
        INTO TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
          (
            SPAN_ID,
            LINK_ID,
            CREATED_BY,
            MAINTENANCEZONECODE,
            MAINTENANCEZONENAME,
            MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH,
            SPAN_TYPE,
            FSA_UG,
            FSA_AERIAL
          )
          VALUES
          (
            PSPAN_ID,
            PLINK_ID,
            PCREATED_BY,
            PMAINTENANCEZONECODE,
            PMAINTENANCEZONENAME,
            --PMAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH,
            PNELENGTH,
            PSPAN_TYPE,
            PUGLENGTH,
            PARLENGTH
          )RETURNING JOB_ID INTO PJOB_ID;
        IF PJOB_ID > 0 THEN
        BEGIN
            INSERT
            INTO TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
              (
                JOB_ID,
                STATUS_ID,
                HOTO_OFFERED_DATE,
                APPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
                ISABDMISSING,
                HOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH,
                NE_SPAN_LENGTH,
                CREATED_BY,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE,
                MODIFIED_BY,
                MODIFIED_DATE,
                APPROVED_BY,
                APPROVED_DATE,
                FSA_UG,
                FSA_AERIAL
              )
              VALUES
              (
                PJOB_ID,
                PSTATUS_ID,
                TO_DATE(PHOTO_OFFERED_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
                PISABDMISSING,
                PHOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH,
                --PMAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH,
                PNELENGTH,
                PCREATED_BY,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
                SYSDATE,
                PCREATED_BY,
                SYSDATE,
                PCREATED_BY,
                SYSDATE,
                -- PUG_LENGTH,
              --  PAR_LENGTH
                PUGLENGTH,
                PARLENGTH
              )RETURNING JOB_PROGRESS_ID INTO PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
          END;
          END IF;
          IF PJOB_PROGRESS_ID > 0 THEN
          BEGIN
            POUTMSG := 'SUCCESS|'||PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
            COMMIT;
          END;
          ELSE
          BEGIN
            POUTMSG := 'FAILED|Record not created';
            ROLLBACK;
          END;
          END IF;
      END;
      ELSE
      BEGIN
          POUTMSG := 'EXISTS|Record already exists';
      END;
      END IF;
  EXCEPTION  
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
      ERROR_MESSAGE := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
      ROLLBACK;
      POUTMSG := 'ERROR|Error ocurred on record creation';
      PKG_FIBER_HOTO_COMP_TEST.INS_ERRORLOG(PCREATED_BY,PSPAN_ID||PLINK_ID,'DB : INS_WORKFLOW',ERROR_CODE||' : '||ERROR_MESSAGE);
END INS_WORKFLOW;
```

Also below is the table description

```
TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS

Name                        Null     Type           
--------------------------- -------- -------------- 
JOB_ID                      NOT NULL NUMBER         PK
SPAN_ID                              NVARCHAR2(100) 
LINK_ID                              NVARCHAR2(100) 
CREATED_BY                           NVARCHAR2(200) 
CREATED_DATE                NOT NULL DATE           
MAINTENANCEZONECODE                  NVARCHAR2(50)  
MAINTENANCEZONENAME                  NVARCHAR2(100) 
MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH            NUMBER         
SPAN_TYPE                            NVARCHAR2(20)  
JOB_FLAG                             NUMBER         
MISSING_ABD_LENGTH                   NUMBER(38,10)  
REOFFERFLAG                          VARCHAR2(10)   
FSA_ID                               NVARCHAR2(8)   
FSA_COMMON                           NUMBER         
FSA_UG                               NUMBER         
FSA_AERIAL                           NUMBER         
FSA_MDU                              NUMBER         
MISSING_ABD_UG                       NUMBER         
MISSING_ABD_AR                       NUMBER         
CALCULATED_LENGTH                    NUMBER         
RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY          NUMBER 


TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS

Name                  Null     Type           
--------------------- -------- -------------- 
JOB_PROGRESS_ID       NOT NULL NUMBER        
JOB_ID                         NUMBER      FK   
STATUS_ID                      NUMBER         
HOTO_OFFERED_DATE              DATE           
HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE           DATE           
LIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE            DATE           
APPROVED_BY                    NVARCHAR2(200) 
APPROVED_DATE                  DATE           
REJECTED_BY                    NVARCHAR2(200) 
REJECTED_DATE                  DATE           
APPROV_REJECT_REMARK           NVARCHAR2(255) 
DELAY_REASON                   NVARCHAR2(255) 
ISABDMISSING                   NUMBER         
HOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH            NUMBER         
LIT_OFFERED_LENGTH             NUMBER         
HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH             NUMBER         
LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH              NUMBER         
ABD_COMPLETED_LENGTH           NUMBER         
NE_SPAN_LENGTH                 NUMBER         
CREATED_BY                     NVARCHAR2(200) 
CREATED_DATE          NOT NULL DATE           
MODIFIED_BY                    NVARCHAR2(200) 
MODIFIED_DATE                  DATE           
UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID            NUMBER         
UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME          NVARCHAR2(200) 
UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID            NUMBER         
UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME          NVARCHAR2(200) 
UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE          DATE           
JOB_PROGRESS_FLAG     NOT NULL NUMBER         
HOTO_OFFER_LEN_UPD_BY          NVARCHAR2(200) 
FSA_COMMON                     NUMBER         
FSA_UG                         NUMBER         
FSA_AERIAL                     NUMBER         
FSA_MDU                        NUMBER         
FSA_UG_ACTUAL                  NUMBER         
FSA_AERIAL_ACTUAL              NUMBER         
FSA_MDU_ACTUAL                 NUMBER
```

Comment: what is the error you get ? so you are running in parallel at the same time this procedure and you say "RESTRICT INSERT DATA IN MASTER IF CHILD HAS A RECORD FOR THE SYSDATE" What do you mean by that ? in which field of the child table should we look for ??

Comment: @RobertoHernandez: Yes the data is inserted parallel. For looking in child table we can have it at `CREATED_DATE` so what i want is, if the created date for that `job_id` is their for that date, then another entry should not be inserted in child table on that date..

Comment: the table 'TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS' has the FK by JOB_PROGRESS_ID. But where is the primary key of this table ??

Comment: you still did not say where the PK in the child table is. I know now that the relationship is based on the JOB_ID, and I guess that the JOB_PROGRESS_ID is the PK in the child table, right ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez: okay, yes the JOB_PROGRESS_ID is the PK in child table

Comment: @RobertoHernandez: any other query mate ? do let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218798/discussion-between-hud-and-roberto-hernandez).

Comment: This is the key point: *"sometimes if we try to insert the same records with two different browsers duplicacy is happening in child table."* Your problem lies not in this procedures per se but in **the architectural flaw which allows two sessions to manipulate the same job simultaneously**. There are various ways of approaching this, but which is the correct solution will depend on the business processes which lead up to these insert statements. The solution might be to change this procedure but it is just as likely to be changing something upstream. We don't have enough info to tell.

Comment: @APC: I agree with you on this, but can we do something with the existing procedure to maintain the process. Additional information can be provided if required

Comment: @hud, sorry I can't open chat with my laptop. working policy ;). Anyway, as dirty solution  I guess you could count the records in the child table for the same jobid and creation date = sysdate  after the insert in the parent table. if the counter is 0 then you insert in child, if not then you do nothing, however in this case you have a rollback. By the way, why the procedure uses so  many begin end blocks ??

Comment: @hud, I will propose an answer, but take it with precaution because I am still don't understand the logic behind those inserts

Comment: @hud  sure mate, what happens ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez: will explain you in a bit on your answer posted below in few mins

Comment: @RobertoHernandez: are u their, lets assume there is MAINTENANCEZONECODE in progress table.. now how will i check the condition as per my last requirement ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez what is `XXX` in `c.MAINTENANCEZONECODE,'XXX'` ?? didnt got you

Comment: when you have NULLs, you need to use NVL to make the join work. I used XXX as a replace when the field is null. NULL to NULL is not comparable in Oracle, I put XXX as a string to replace the null, you can put anything you want there. I guess this combination of characters don't happen often in the data

Comment: okay so that's for checking null values. Great thanks let me try this one too..which one would be fast and accurate will use that..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to see if this solution matches your requirements. Key factors:

- I remove all begin end blocks which were unnecessary. You only need to specify blocks when you want to control the exceptions on those blocks.
- If the child is there for a parent already inserted , that is already control by the transaction level READ UNCOMMITTED. So I can count the records in child for the same P_JOBID when the child is there for the parent created_date
- I used to_char over the column because I don't know which NLS_DATE settings you have.

Let me know any doubts you might have.

**Update**

A message can be displayed as long as the procedure is executed using SERVEROUPUT ON or DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE and the session is configured to capture the output.

```
PROCEDURE INS_WORKFLOW
(
    PSPAN_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.SPAN_ID%TYPE,
    PLINK_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.LINK_ID%TYPE,
    PCREATED_BY IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.CREATED_BY%TYPE,
    PMAINTENANCEZONECODE IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.MAINTENANCEZONECODE%TYPE,
    PMAINTENANCEZONENAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.MAINTENANCEZONENAME%TYPE,
    PMAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH%TYPE,
    PSTATUS_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.STATUS_ID%TYPE,
    PHOTO_OFFERED_DATE IN NVARCHAR2,
    PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.APPROV_REJECT_REMARK%TYPE,
    PISABDMISSING IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.ISABDMISSING%TYPE,
    PHOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.HOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH%TYPE,
    PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID%TYPE,
    PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME%TYPE,
    PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID%TYPE,
    PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME%TYPE,
    PSPAN_TYPE IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.SPAN_TYPE%TYPE,
    POUTMSG OUT NVARCHAR2
) 
AS
PJOB_PROGRESS_ID NUMBER:=0;
PJOB_ID NUMBER :=0;
PCNT_JOBID NUMBER :=-1;
PNELENGTH NUMBER:=0;
PUGLENGTH NUMBER:=0;
PARLENGTH NUMBER:=0;
VCOUNTERCHILD PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    --execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format = ''DD/MM/YYYY''';
    IF ( PSPAN_TYPE = 'INTRACITY' OR PSPAN_TYPE = 'ENTERPRISE' ) 
    THEN
        SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) INTO PCNT_JOBID 
        FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
        WHERE LINK_ID = PLINK_ID
        AND MAINTENANCEZONECODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE;
            
        SELECT  ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH,
        ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS UG_LEN
       ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%CLAMP%'  THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS AR_LEN
        INTO PNELENGTH,PUGLENGTH,PARLENGTH
          FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER 
    --FROM APP_FTTX.span@sat
              WHERE RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID = PLINK_ID
              AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
              AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE
              GROUP BY RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE;
    ELSIF PSPAN_TYPE = 'INTERCITY' 
    THEN
          SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) INTO PCNT_JOBID 
              FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
              WHERE SPAN_ID = PSPAN_ID
              AND MAINTENANCEZONECODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE;
        ---CR981 implemenation
          IF LENGTH(PSPAN_ID) = 9  
          THEN
           SELECT  ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH,
           ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS UG_LEN
          ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%CLAMP%'  THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS AR_LEN
               INTO PNELENGTH,PUGLENGTH,PARLENGTH
           FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER 
           --FROM APP_FTTX.span@sat
              WHERE RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID = PSPAN_ID
              AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
              AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE
              GROUP BY RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE;
         ELSE
             SELECT  ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH,
              ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS UG_LEN
             ,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%CLAMP%'  THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS AR_LEN
              INTO PNELENGTH,PUGLENGTH,PARLENGTH
              FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER 
              --FROM APP_FTTX.span@sat
              WHERE RJ_SPAN_ID = PSPAN_ID
              AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
              AND (NOT REGEXP_LIKE (RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,'_(9)','i') OR RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID IS NULL)
              AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE
              GROUP BY RJ_SPAN_ID,RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE;
         END IF;
    END IF;

    IF PCNT_JOBID = 0 
    THEN
        INSERT
        INTO TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
          (
            SPAN_ID,
            LINK_ID,
            CREATED_BY,
            MAINTENANCEZONECODE,
            MAINTENANCEZONENAME,
            MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH,
            SPAN_TYPE,
            FSA_UG,
            FSA_AERIAL
          )
          VALUES
          (
            PSPAN_ID,
            PLINK_ID,
            PCREATED_BY,
            PMAINTENANCEZONECODE,
            PMAINTENANCEZONENAME,
            --PMAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH,
            PNELENGTH,
            PSPAN_TYPE,
            PUGLENGTH,
            PARLENGTH
          )RETURNING JOB_ID INTO PJOB_ID;
          IF PJOB_ID > 0 
          THEN
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO VCOUNTERCHILD FROM 
   TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS c INNER JOIN  TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS p 
        ON c.job_id=p.job_id and c.job_id = PJOB_ID and 
      to_char(p.CREATED_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy') = to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy') 
        and nvl(c.span_id,'XXX') = nvl(p.span_id,'XXX') and 
        nvl(c.MAINTENANCEZONECODE,'XXX') = nvl(p.MAINTENANCEZONECODE,'XXX') ;
            -- if the child is not there we insert
            if VCOUNTERCHILD = 0
            then 
                insert INTO TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
              (
                JOB_ID,
                STATUS_ID,
                HOTO_OFFERED_DATE,
                APPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
                ISABDMISSING,
                HOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH,
                NE_SPAN_LENGTH,
                CREATED_BY,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE,
                MODIFIED_BY,
                MODIFIED_DATE,
                APPROVED_BY,
                APPROVED_DATE,
                FSA_UG,
                FSA_AERIAL
              )
              VALUES
              (
                PJOB_ID,
                PSTATUS_ID,
                TO_DATE(PHOTO_OFFERED_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
                PISABDMISSING,
                PHOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH,
                --PMAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH,
                PNELENGTH,
                PCREATED_BY,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
                SYSDATE,
                PCREATED_BY,
                SYSDATE,
                PCREATED_BY,
                SYSDATE,
                -- PUG_LENGTH,
              --  PAR_LENGTH
                PUGLENGTH,
                PARLENGTH
              )RETURNING JOB_PROGRESS_ID INTO PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
            end if;
          END IF;
          IF PJOB_PROGRESS_ID > 0 
          THEN
              POUTMSG := 'SUCCESS|'||PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
              COMMIT;
          ELSE
             POUTMSG := 'WARNING|Record not created - Already a child record for job id '||PJOB_ID||' ';
        -- I will remove the rollback. Here it does not make sense as you don't need to rollback the whole transaction
        -- ROLLBACK;
        dbms_output.put_line ( POUTMSG );
          END IF;
      ELSE
          POUTMSG := 'EXISTS|Record already exists';
      END IF;
  EXCEPTION  
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
      ERROR_MESSAGE := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
      ROLLBACK;
      POUTMSG := 'ERROR|Error ocurred on record creation';
      PKG_FIBER_HOTO_COMP_TEST.INS_ERRORLOG(PCREATED_BY,PSPAN_ID||PLINK_ID,'DB : INS_WORKFLOW',ERROR_CODE||' : '||ERROR_MESSAGE);
END INS_WORKFLOW;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218902/discussion-on-answer-by-roberto-hernandez-restrict-inserting-data-in-master-tabl).

Comment: Thanks mate, I have accepted this answer.. If in coming days needed any suggestion will let u know. Thank you so much